# Twitter API App auth, CORS issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, twitter, redux

I am trying to fetch all the tweets from hillary and trump for a job proposal as a junior dev (starting out :)), and I keep running into a CORS problem. Any help would mean the world to me!

I'm trying to use Application Only based authentication and not User based, so I got the bearer token, my key and secret, stored them in a separate page, used them to fill

```
`var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  bearer_token: ''
});`
```

and tried to make a get request with it as detailed on the npm twitter documentation with:

```
`twitter.client.get(`${twitter.TWITTER_URL}search/tweets.json?q=@realDonaldTrump&result_type=mixed&count=2`, null, function(error, tweets, response) {
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(response);
        console.log(tweets);
    })`
```

However I run into a CORS error when I just omit the params, and when I set params as null (as in the example above), it breaks. Any suggestions?

P.S. also, they suggest storing the sensitive keys in the `params.env`  how do I do that? I just stored them in another file and imported them, then .gitignore the keys. Here is my result:

```
`import * as keys from "../../API_KEYS/API_KEYS";`

`import Twitter from "twitter";`


`export const TWITTER_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"`

`export const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: keys.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: keys.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  bearer_token: keys.BEARER_TOKEN
});`
```

And here is their suggestion:

```
`var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  bearer_token: process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
});`
```

Comment: *solved the null params ^_^ took query out of the url instead. Still got cors and wondering about params :) if possible

Comment: The Twitter API does not support CORS, are you running this from a browser, or on a server?

Comment: I am running it from a browser. Would it make sense to mount a lazy node express server to communicate with Twitter?

Comment: Ok, I think the only way to get it done is to run a server through a proxy and make a request then. I'll give it a whirl

Comment: Yup. Ok, well the only way is to set up a server and run your requests through said server, and then making sure you have a proxy set up. Then you front end can talk to Twitter through your server